# Setting the cookie works in 80% of the cases, cannot figure out why it does not in the remaining 20%

Tags: cookies

I set cookie on my landing pages with loading this JS code into an iframe (iframe.com/cookie.html):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays, exhours, exmins, exsecs) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * exhours * exmins * exsecs * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; SameSite=None; Secure ;" + expires + ";path=/";
    }
setCookie("source", source, 600, 24, 60, 60);
```

Then I retrieve it with a php on iframe.com/getcookie.php :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if(isset($_COOKIE['source'])){ $source= $_COOKIE['source'];}
```

In 80% of the cases, no problem. But I can't figure out the remaining 20%. I have never been able to reproduce the issue myself but I track that about 20% of my users cannot retrieve the cookie value.

1. Ad / Cookie blockers ?
2. Should I set a different header in the iframe.com/cookie.html ?
3. Different settings in the setCookie function ?

Comment: Check your network tab, are they sent?

Comment: Yes. I have never been able to reproduce a failed set of cookie. It always works when I do it and it works for about 80% of the users.

Comment: Do you know anything about these users? Maybe a `User Agent` header?

Comment: And I assume you tried a few privacy plugins, Firefox on "Enhanced Tracking Protection" module and Safari. Everything is going towards less tracking by default and both Safari and Firefox are going to be more strict than Chrome.

Comment: I have access to UA and all users (working and non working) are Chrome (no FF or SF)